# how to extract 45 cycles from bunch of waveforms

Tags: filters

I want to extract 45 number of cycles from the bunch of cycle which is similar to sine wave of varying amplitude. please help me to do so. in this picture i have capture only 45 cycles but i have continuous wave forms.i.e after each 45 cycles the signal is repeating.

thanking you,

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to extract the signal that corresponds to the gear making 1 full turn?

Answer (score 1):

For best performance in the presence of noise, I recommend "locking" onto the cyclical signal using a Phase-Lock-Loop (PLL) approach. Then you can feed the PLL output (which will be a cleaner representation of your signal and can be a digital square wave if desired) into a digital counter, which you can then count to 45 after resetting the counter at any position desired.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way (imo) is to write a peak detection algorithm, then have a variable that stores the amount of times a peak is found.